# Keeping changes to auto-generated WCF RIA Services Domain Classes

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

During the creation of an auto-generated WCF domain service class based off entity framework, a file that contains the metadata for the EF classes is also created.  In this file, I've had to add the [Include()] attribute to a number of classes so that I can include these properties during WCF calls.  My problem is, I sometimes have to changed the data model.  This requires that I remove the entire metadata file along with the domain services file, and regenerate the entire thing and then go back and add the [Include()] attributes back to the correct properties.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a way to keep the [Include()] attributes in a separate file so that I don't have to continuously go back and add them in?